# Dave Johnson Facebook (PH 2.1.0 Errors)

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, cordova

Will this [plugin](https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect) work with phonegap 2.1.0? I've installed this successfully before on 1.8.1 but am working on a project with 2.1.0 and it doesn't seem to work. It gives me a pop up js error:

"Cordova variable does not exist. Check that you have included cordova.js correctly"

Which might just be a meaningless error. But when I click "login" it takes me to the facebook app window and tells me that the app bundle id has not been included. I have added the bundle id to the bottom of the index page and in the info.plist file.

Any thoughts on what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing the bundle ID entry in your App Dashboard settings. So go to http://developers.facebook.com/apps and enter the bundle iD that matches your Xcode project.

There's a Cordova 2.1.0 / Facebook 3.1 branch for PhoneGap that you can also try out:
https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect/tree/pg2.1-ios3.1